# Provide alternate (international) spelling for defined Swagger route

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I'm working on an API spec in swagger that has an endpoint:

```
/authorizations
```

I would like to define an alternative spelling (authorisations) for this endpoint as well. Is this possible? Or do I need to define a separate route for each spelling?

```
/authorizations:
    get:
      description: Returns a list of authorizations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround is to define another path that [`$ref`s the original path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44150758/113116), this way you end up with two copies of the same path.

```yaml
paths:
  /authorizations:
    get:
      description: Returns a list of authorizations
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
  /authorisations:
    $ref: '#/paths/~1authorizations'
```

One limitation of this technique is that you cannot have `operationId` for these paths, because both paths will end up with the same ID, which is not allowed.

If you need to have different `operationId` in paths, you'll need to define the 2nd path in the usual way (i.e. copy-paste the definition from the 1st path).

Answer (score 2):

Swagger currently does not support overloading/aliasing path definitions. I don't recall ever seeing such a request, but you're more than welcome on open an issue on https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec asking to add support for it in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/213 where one suggestion is to define a "renamed" path by using a 308 redirect:

```
  /original-x:
    description: Redirects to the new X
    get:
      responses:
        '308':
          description: This resource has been moved
          headers:
            Location:
              schema:
                type: string
                default: /new-x
```

(I've not seen another means to implement this cleanly.)