# Swagger 2.0: Multiple Path objects with different paths but same request and response

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Due to some backward compatibility reasons, I need to support both the paths `/ab` and `/a-b`.

The request and response objects are going to be the same for both of the paths.

Can I have something like the following in my Swagger spec so that I do not have to repeat the request and response object definitions for both the paths.

```
paths:
  /ab:
  /a-b:
    post:
    ...
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can have a path item that references another path item:

```yaml
paths:
  /ab:
    post:
      summary: ...
      ...
      responses:
        ...

  /a-b:
    $ref: '#/paths/~1ab'   # <------------
```

Here, `~1ab` is an encoded version of `/ab` (see below).

One **limitation of this approach** is that you cannot have `operationId` in all operations of the referenced path item. This is because the copy of the path ends up with the same `operationId` values, but `operationId` must be unique.

#### Encoding $ref values

If the characters `~` and `/` are present in node names (as in case of path names, e.g. `/ab`) they must be encoded: `~` as `~0`, and `/` as `~1`:

- `/ab` → `~1ab` → `$ref: '#/paths/~1ab'`
- `/foo/bar` → `~1foo~1bar` → `$ref: '#/paths/~1foo~1bar'`
- `/ab~cd` → `~1ab~0cd` → `#/paths/~1ab~0cd`

Additionally, `{` `}` and other characters not allowed in URI fragment identifiers ([RFC 3986, section 3.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5)) need to be percent-encoded. For example, `{` becomes `%7B`, and `}` becomes `%7D`.

- `/{zzz}`
  → `~1{zzz}`  ( / replaced with ~1)
  → `~1%7Bzzz%7D`  (percent-encoded)
  → `$ref: '#/paths/~1%7Bzzz%7D'`
- `/foo/{zzz}`
  → `~1foo~1{zzz}`  ( / replaced with ~1)
  → `~1foo~1%7Bzzz%7D`  (percent-encoded)
  → `$ref: '#/paths/~1foo~1%7Bzzz%7D'`

Note that you need to encode just the path name and not the `#/paths/` prefix.

Comment: The path also has some template characters like: `paths: /ab/{c}/{d}`. When it is referred from `/a-b`, do the curly braces also need to be escaped?

Comment: @bdev03: No, curly braces are fine. Only `/` and `~` need to be escaped.

Comment: @Helen this appears not to be true anymore. With curly brackets swagger with openapi 3 gave me a syntax error (while surprisingly working nevertheless...?). The error was `$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs`. To fix this error, replace `{` with `%7B` and `}` with `%7D`.

Comment: @UeliDeSchwert You are right. I updated the answer.

Comment: Is this only for OpenAPI 3.0 ?   We're on 2.0 here.

Comment: @DaveyBoy This is supported in both OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0.

Comment: Using OpenAPI 2.0 and the python-flask server the validation fails with the error "swagger_spec_validator.common.SwaggerValidationError: Duplicate operationId". Is there a way around this?

Comment: @SamuelO.D. No workaround. As explained in the answer - *"One limitation of this approach is that you cannot have `operationId` in all operations of the referenced path item. This is because the copy of the path ends up with the same `operationId` values, but `operationId` must be unique."*