# How to use $ref to reference a path from another OpenAPI file?

Tags: openapi

[Here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) it says I could refer to the definition in another file for an individual path, but the example seems to refer to a whole file, instead of a single path definition under the `paths` object. How to assign an individual path in another file's `paths` object?

For example, I have `Anotherfile.yaml` that contains the `/a/b` path:

```yaml
paths:
  /a/b:
    post:
```

In another file, I use `$ref` to reference the `/a/b` path as follows:

```yaml
paths:
  /c/d:
    $ref: 'Anotherfile.yaml#/paths/a/b'
```

but this gives an error:

> Could not find paths/a/b in contents of ./Anotherfile.yaml

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When referencing paths, you need to [escape the path name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164413/113116) by replacing `/` with `~1`, so that `/a/b` becomes `~1a~1b`. Note that you escape just the path name and not the `#/paths/` prefix.

```
$ref: 'Anotherfile.yaml#/paths/~1a~1b'
```

Comment: BTW, why "to reference sth" not  "to refer sth" >.<

Comment: @Tiina I'm not a native speaker. Is "to refer smth" more correct grammatically? [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md) uses the term "referencing", e.g. "if referencing a schema, ..."

Comment: Another use case I've come along is referencing an `Object Schema`'s `property` (part of `properties`) in another `Object Schema`. One can achieve this via a more specific JSON pointer -- `$ref: './my-other-schema#/properties/propToImport`

Comment: This answer doesn't work.   I get the error, using spec 3.0.1 :
`Error: Invalid reference token: `.  .  Same error with JSON and YAML.

Comment: @djangofan I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77968275/113116) your other question. The `$ref` in your example was encoded incorrectly.