# How can I create OpenAPI spec files having $ref to other sub-files? Is this possible?

Tags: json, swagger, openapi, json-ref

I am unable to get OpenAPI spec Swagger "external refs" to work because Swagger rendering gives me an exception.

I must have this to make editing giant swagger documents more manageable since I don't have an auto-generator (due to architecture of azure sdk)

I am using 3.0.1 version, trying to do something like this:

```
paths:
  /v1:
    $ref: 'first-api.yaml#/paths/~1v1'
  /v2:
    $ref: 'second-api.yaml#/paths/~1v2'
```

The answer in this question doesn't work:
[How to use $ref to reference a path from another OpenAPI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909124/how-to-use-ref-to-reference-a-path-from-another-openapi-file)

The error I get looks like this (in IntelliJ-IDEA IDE using the `OpenAI (Swagger) Editor`  plugin):

[image]

Would appreciate a link to an example project proving this works.

I tried it here, for example, and it fails:

- master json: https://www.npoint.io/docs/1409525a51f14540ab0a
- test1
  json: https://www.npoint.io/docs/ae1d3959a91b828a3098
- test2 json:
  https://www.npoint.io/docs/775e7edb2c1ccb01a735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `$ref` to specify the path starting with an explicit reference to the current directory.  That is, prepend the path with `./`

```
paths:
  /v1:
    $ref: './first-api.yaml#/paths/~1v1'
```

Comment: I was successful when using web hyperlinks.  I could have swore I tried the suggestion above (multiple times), but today, when re-trying it, it's working for me.

Comment: Yeh, I've found path handling is not terribly well specfied/document in OpenAPI.  Made worse by the official openapitools project and underlying parsing APIs tends to be very finicky with paths.  If you dig into the official libraries you'll find many issues around handling local reference paths - especially on Windows platforms.
For example - might you have been trying to use a 3.1.0 spec when you previously tried?  Because even paths prefixed with the current path are broken when using 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Change

```json
  "paths": {
    "/test": {
      "$ref": "https://api.npoint.io/ae1d3959a91b828a3098#/paths/test"
    },
    "/document": {
      "$ref": "https://api.npoint.io/775e7edb2c1ccb01a735#/paths/document"
    }
  },
```

to

```json
  "paths": {
    "/test": {
      "$ref": "https://api.npoint.io/ae1d3959a91b828a3098#/paths/~1test"
    },
    "/document": {
      "$ref": "https://api.npoint.io/775e7edb2c1ccb01a735#/paths/~1document"
    }
  },
```

Note the references look like `...#/paths/~1test` and not `...#/paths/test`. `~1` is the [escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164413/113116) used in path item references.

The fixed version is rendered correctly in Swagger Editor:

[image]

Comment: Your right, that worked!    I tried that.  You can see in my original question that I was doing that.      I admit you got it working using URLs, but I am still not convinced when using  local file locators.

Comment: I was only able to get it to work by replacing my file URIs with http URLs