# When forward slashes need to be escaped in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am trying to understand in which case the forward slash needs to be escaped when writing OpenApi specification document.
Here (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) is written:

```
/ and ~ are special characters in JSON Pointers, and need to be escaped when used literally 
(for example, in path names).
For example, to refer to the path /blogs/{blog_id}/new~posts, you would use:
$ref: '#/paths/~1blogs~1{blog_id}~1new~0posts'
```

In this example the first two forward slashes are not escaped?

Then later the following example is given:

```
$ref: '../resources/users.yaml'

$ref: '../resources/users-by-id.yaml'
```

And these paths are not escaped?

In which case all (or part of the) forward slashes need to be escaped with ~1 ?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164413/113116) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Pointer part of a `$ref` is the part after the `#` fragment delimiter. Before that is the relative or absolute URI, where forward slashes do not need to be escaped.

In the section following the `#`, the values of things like `pathItem` keys which contain forward slashes do need to be escaped.

Comment: in the URI "#/paths/~1blogs~1{blog_id}~1new~0posts" the # symbol is at the beginning. However 2 of the slashes after it are not escaped and the other 2 need to be escaped?
Why /paths/ being after the # symbol is not escaped?

Comment: The unescaped slashes are **between** the elements of the JSON Pointer, `#/` is the pointer to the root of the document, then you have an element which takes you to the `paths` object, then you need an element that takes you to the `/blogs/{blog_id}/new~posts` key, **but** those slashes would look like JSON Pointer element separators if you just did `#/paths/blogs/{blog_id}/new~posts`, so this is where the escaping comes in. So - where you have a transition between elements of the source document, you need an unescaped slash, and where you are encoding one **string**, escape them.