# OpenApi - fail to map the same $ref to 2 paths

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an `API` that is in use by our clients in the production environment.
We decided to change the path, but since the old path is still being in use we would like to keep it as well for the time being.

I tried to add another path for the same object, but the `open api` generator fails when I try to run it.

```
  /v3/stores/{store_id}/old_path:
    $ref: '#/operationObj'
  /v3/stores/{store_id}/groups/new_path
    $ref: '#/operationObj'
```

This

```
  /v3/stores/{store_id}/old_path:
    ....
  /v3/stores/{store_id}/groups/new_path
    $ref: '#/operationObj'
```

And this

```
  /v3/stores/{store_id}/old_path:
  /v3/stores/{store_id}/groups/new_path
    $ref: '#/operationObj'
```

But keep on failing. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible or creating a duplication for the `operationObj` is the correct way to make it work? (I tried creating an `operationObjDuplication` object and the generator succeeded).

Any leads, please?

Comment: Can you paste the error here? It would be better.

Comment: Your old url and new url both use the same operationObj ?

Comment: @ShubhamRanjan, I want them both to use the same operationObj

Comment: @ankush__, the error I'm getting is related to issues with the specification. But it's a false error, since when I reference it only to one path everything is fine

Comment: I think you are missing : symbol at the end of new path. That's the only thing I can say. I have been openAPI for some time. Have referenced same objects on multiple places. No errors like that. If can paste error that's only way we can move forward.

Comment: Use example #2, but change the `$ref` in the new_path as follows: `$ref: '#/paths/~1v3~1stores~1%7Bstore_id%7D~1old_path'`. See the [linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44150758/113116) for an explanation.