# With OpenAPI 3, can I create an aliased path that mimics everything from the original except the endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

I'm using Spring Boot, and I have a Yaml file defining some endpoints. I need to alias one of the endpoints to have a different endpoint, but the functionality is exactly the same.

As an example, if I have a spec as follows:

```
openapi: '3.0.1'

servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8080/api

paths:
  /v3/users
    .... (remainder of endpoint spec)
```

What I want to add to this, from what I've read, is:

```
  /globalusers/v3/users
    $ref: '#/paths/~1v3~1users
```

When I do this, the generated Spring API doesn't include the new RequestMapping. I tried duplicating the whole **/v3/users** definition and putting that in as well, but no change.

Either I'm missing something or misinterpreting what I read. All help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: The `$ref` is correct - assuming there's a `:` after the path name (i.e., `/globalusers/v3/users:`). Can you elaborate on _"the generated Spring API doesn't include the new RequestMapping"_? What code generator do you use (Swagger Codegen, OpenAPI Generator), what result do you expect and what is the actual result? Also, do the operations within the `/v3/users` endpoint have `operationId`?

Comment: Yes, there is a colon after the path name; accidentally left if off. The code generator being used is an in-house one (no idea why it had to be reinvented). Does anything more have o be added, or is the path and $ref enough? I'm expecting to see another RequestMapping with ```/globalusers/v3/users``` . Yes, the ```/v3/users``` does have an ```operationId```.

Comment: You should remove `operationId` as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164413/113116), otherwise both endpoints get the same ID which is not allowed. Then bring up the issue with the developers/mainteiners of your in-house codegen. Maybe your codegen cannot handle path $refs properly.

Comment: @Helen does the rest of the path definition get copied and entered under the $ref, or is the $ref all that's required? I'm guessing that since you said to remove the ```operationId```, the full endpoint definition is used.

Comment: The `$ref` alone is enough. `$ref` works by replacing itself with the content of the referenced node.

Answer (score 5):

You can create path's aliases using [`$ref`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)

```yaml
paths:
  /authorizations:
    get:
      description: Returns a list of authorizations
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
  /authorisations:
    $ref: '#/paths/~1authorizations'
```

Example taken from [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/213#issuecomment-812977731).

The `~1` is escaping the character `/` because the path itself has also a `/`, that is, `/authorizations`