# OpenAPI and AWS CDK: Using $ref to duplicate an endpoint doesn't create Operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-cdk

I found [this documentation on swagger.io](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150758/swagger-2-0-multiple-path-objects-with-different-paths-but-same-request-and-res/44164413#44164413) showing how a path could be referenced within an OpenAPI spec in order to copy the definition of one path to another.

I have tried this within an AWS CDK project which uses the "SpecRestApi" construct backed by lambda functions, and although AWS API Gateway does create the duplicate resources, these do not have any operations defined on them.

Example openAPI spec:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
paths:
  /client/address:
    post:
      summary: Set client address
      requestBody: 
        # standard definition of content/schema omitted for brevity
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        # lambda integration details omitted for brevity
      # other standard properties omitted for brevity
  /address:
    $ref: '#/paths/~1client~1address'
```

This executes without error and publishes my API Gateway, and the /client/address resource contains the POST method and works correctly. The AWS API Gateway console also shows that the /address resource has been created, however it does not have any methods defined on it.

I would have expected either an error message preventing deployment and letting me know what I hahve done wrong, or else for both URL resources /client/address and /address to have the POST

Is this a known limitation of API Gateway / CDK / SpecRestApi? Or have I done something obviously wrong in the above?